# Can silverlight 5 access a USB port via .net library

Tags: .net, silverlight, dll, usb

I have a fingerprint reader that comes with a .NET library dll to interface with. Is it possible to access that fingerprint reader (by way of the dll) using silverlight?

Are there then other ways to do so if silverlight can't do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work if the dll is registered in COM